# Problem Inserting Report Viewer into WPF Application using WindowsformsHost

Tags: wpf, windows, forms, integration, reportviewer

I am trying to create a popup from my WPF application which shows a report viewer hosted in a WindowsFormsHost
however I am having problems with the following Xaml

```
<Page x:Class="FIS3.ReportViewer.ReportViewer"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration;assembly=WindowsFormsIntegration"
Title="MapViewer">
<Grid>
    <my:WindowsFormsHost>

    </my:WindowsFormsHost>
    <Label Name="exampleText" Content="this is the Report Viewer ..." />
</Grid>
```

I am getting a build error notifying me that 
"The type 'my:WindowsFormsHost' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built"

have I made an error in my XAML
I have added WindowsFormsIntegration as a reference to my project.

Thanks for your help

Col

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx), WindowsFormsHost is included in the default Xaml namespace ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation") - though you do need to reference WindowsFormsIntegration, as you have done. Have you tried referencing WindowsFormsHost with no namespace prefix?

```
<Page x:Class="FIS3.ReportViewer.ReportViewer"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 Title="MapViewer">
 <Grid>
   <WindowsFormsHost>

   <WindowsFormsHost>
  <Label Name="exampleText" Content="this is the Report Viewer ..." />
 </Grid>
```

Comment: Hi 
thanks for the feed back. I just tried the code above and I'm still getting the same error
I was wondering if it is an issue with the Page tag as anywhere I have seen this implemented the window tag is the opening node

Comment: Having Page as root rather than Window shouldn't be a problem. Are you sure this is a build error, and not an error reported by the XAML designer. You could try turning off the XAML designer: right click a XAML file, select Open With, select XML Editor then Set as Default. Restart visual studio to make sure the XAML designer isn't loaded, then try building your project.

Comment: Hi Samuel 

Unfortunately it is a build error I have turned off the XAML designer as per your previous suggestion and I am getting the error
"The tag 'WindowsFormsHost' does not exist in XML namspace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation', Line 6 Position 8."

Thanks for the help with this.  I really don't knw what is gone wrong with it.

Regards
Colm

Comment: Resolved this error 
I had to remove all my references and add them all back in again which eventually removed the error. I don't know why it was showing up as a build error but its working now. I probably didn't have the correct reference in the first instance

thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 3):

There is a second solution to this that people seem to have overlooked. I scratched my head on this one for a good 20 minutes. No solution, including this one, would work. Turns out the solution for me was to add:

WindowsFormsIntegration

to my references

after I realized that based on:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx

that this uses the WindowsFormsIntegration.dll. It seemed to have been missing from my references.

Hope this helps!